# Problems in using "pdfetch"

Tags: r

I am trying to download a time series from this [website](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browse.do?node=9691215) - it is the very last item I am trying to get. I am using **pdfetch** as it is usually quick. It just requires to put the code of the series and the job is done. However, this time I get an error I can't solve. Find below the problem.

```
library(pdfetch)

pdfetch_ECB("ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX")

Error in xts(as.matrix(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(fr[, 2]))), dates,  : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

Can anyone solve it?

Thanks a lot!

I am including my SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Quandl_2.10.0        tsDyn_10-1.2         tseries_0.10-47      quantmod_0.4-15      TTR_0.23-5          
 [6] xts_0.11-2           scales_1.0.0         stargazer_5.2.2      forecast_8.11        readxl_1.3.1        
[11] dynlm_0.3-6          AER_1.2-9            survival_3.1-8       car_3.0-6            carData_3.0-3       
[16] pdfetch_0.2.4        vars_1.5-3           lmtest_0.9-37        urca_1.3-0           strucchange_1.5-2   
[21] sandwich_2.5-1       MASS_7.3-51.5        lubridate_1.7.4      zoo_1.8-6            pastecs_1.3.21      
[26] rvest_0.3.5          xml2_1.2.2           ngram_3.0.4          quanteda_1.5.2       textstem_0.1.4      
[31] koRpus.lang.en_0.1-3 koRpus_0.11-5        sylly_0.1-5          readtext_0.75        pdftools_2.3        
[36] forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.4          purrr_0.3.2          readr_1.3.1         
[41] tidyr_1.0.2          tibble_2.1.3         ggplot2_3.2.1        tidyverse_1.3.0      topicmodels_0.2-8   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] backports_1.1.4       fastmatch_1.1-0       plyr_1.8.4            selectr_0.4-2         lazyeval_0.2.2       
 [6] splines_3.6.2         digest_0.6.21         foreach_1.4.8         htmltools_0.4.0       fansi_0.4.0          
[11] magrittr_1.5          tm_0.7-7              openxlsx_4.1.4        remotes_2.1.0         modelr_0.1.5         
[16] RcppParallel_4.4.3    textshape_1.6.0       askpass_1.1           colorspace_1.4-1      haven_2.2.0          
[21] xfun_0.12             crayon_1.3.4          jsonlite_1.6          iterators_1.0.12      glue_1.3.1           
[26] stopwords_1.0         gtable_0.3.0          spacyr_1.2            abind_1.4-5           qpdf_1.1             
[31] DBI_1.1.0             tseriesChaos_0.1-13.1 qdapRegex_0.7.2       Rcpp_1.0.2            foreign_0.8-74       
[36] deSolve_1.27.1        Formula_1.2-3         textclean_0.9.3       stats4_3.6.2          httr_1.4.1           
[41] modeltools_0.2-22     pkgconfig_2.0.3       XML_3.99-0.3          nnet_7.3-12           dbplyr_1.4.2         
[46] utf8_1.1.4            janitor_1.2.1         tidyselect_0.2.5      labeling_0.3          rlang_0.4.4          
[51] reshape2_1.4.3        munsell_0.5.0         cellranger_1.1.0      tools_3.6.2           cli_2.0.1            
[56] generics_0.0.2        broom_0.5.4           evaluate_0.14         yaml_2.2.0            knitr_1.26           
[61] fs_1.3.1              zip_2.0.4             nlme_3.1-143          slam_0.1-45           compiler_3.6.2       
[66] rstudioapi_0.11       curl_4.1              reprex_0.3.0          syuzhet_1.0.4         stringi_1.4.3        
[71] lattice_0.20-38       Matrix_1.2-18         vctrs_0.2.2           pillar_1.4.3          lifecycle_0.1.0      
[76] data.table_1.12.2     sylly.en_0.1-3        R6_2.4.1              rio_0.5.16            lexicon_1.2.1        
[81] codetools_0.2-16      boot_1.3-24           assertthat_0.2.1      withr_2.1.2           mnormt_1.5-6         
[86] fracdiff_1.5-1        mgcv_1.8-31           parallel_3.6.2        hms_0.5.3             ISOcodes_2019.12.22  
[91] quadprog_1.5-8        grid_3.6.2            timeDate_3043.102     rmarkdown_2.1         NLP_0.2-0
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show your `sessionInfo`

Comment: @NelsonGon just added

Comment: @Rollo99 you could try updating xts to the latest version (v0.12)

Comment: @AllanCameron tried, it  kept saying the same error unfortunately

Comment: Its working perfectly for me....with xts-11_2

Comment: @PKumar which version of `xts` do you have? I can't figure it out why

Comment: @PKumar then I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: same as yours xts_0.11-2  , you may have conflicts in your session, try running conflicts() in your console and see if there are any conflicts in functions, or just restart  R and do this after that

Comment: @PKumar I have many, any advise to solve the conclicts?

Comment: @PKumar it's a locale problem - see my answer

Comment: @Rollo99, the error is coming from xts function , I opened this function and did a ctrl+ F on  "'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'" I saw its there.(You just type xts and hit enter you can see it too), I am not sure what caused this but it seems its coming from xts function...regarding solving the conflicts, sometimes its hard to do it manually, I would rather take a restart, if the problem persists then there can be other causes which can do this, one answer suggests that there can be locale issue, check if that is the case and let us all know.

Comment: @AllanCameron, thanks noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a locale problem, most likely down to the failure of lubridate to parse the unusual English year-month format of the [downloaded csv document](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?SERIES_KEY=ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX&type=csv) in your locale.

I can replicate your error by doing

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Italian_Italy.1252")
pdfetch_ECB("ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX")
#> Error in xts(as.matrix(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(fr[, 2]))), dates,  : 
#>   'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

and fix it by doing

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United Kingdom.1252")
pdfetch_ECB("ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX")
#>            ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX
#> 1997-01-31                   75.45
#> 1997-02-28                   75.52
#> 1997-03-31                   75.59
#> 1997-04-30                   75.61
#> 1997-05-31                   75.71
#> 1997-06-30                   75.76
#> ...
```

So this should work for you:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United Kingdom.1252")
result <- pdfetch_ECB("ICP.M.U2.Y.XEFUN0.3.INX")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Italian_Italy.1252")
```