# I can't download anything with pdfetch_ECB in R because is not working

Tags: r

I tried to download this dataset from European Central Bank but an error occurs.
I realy don't know what is happening also because 1-2 months ago it worked well.

Hope anyone can help me

```
library(vars)
library(tseries)
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)
library(pdfetch)

gdp<-pdfetch_ECB("MNA.Q.Y.I8.W2.S1.S1.B.B1GQ._Z._Z._Z.EUR.LR.GY")

Error in xts(as.matrix(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(fr[, 2]))), dates,  : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

Comment: Did you do any searching? Does this answer the question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262520/problems-in-using-pdfetch

Comment: Maybe it doesn't, but that doesn't relieve you of the responsibility in the future of describing what search efforts you have made and a description of why they did not answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the code you should see a `for`-loop that starts out:

```
for (i in 1:length(identifiers)) {
        req <- GET(paste0("http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?SERIES_KEY=", 
         
                           identifiers[i],
                           "&type=csv"))
```

[Building that URL by hand](https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?SERIES_KEY=%22MNA.Q.Y.I8.W2.S1.S1.B.B1GQ._Z._Z._Z.EUR.LR.GY%22&type=csv%22) and submitting it to my browser brings up this:

> SDW Public is under maintenance
>
> We expect to be back by Saturday 10:00hs CEST

It would be nice if they said *which* Saturday or if they had dated the message, but neither of those bits of information. So you're SOL if you need this immediately. (It would also be nice if pdfetch did a better job of error detection. Seems that getting an HTTP status code of 500 ought to have been anticipated and the user given an appropriate warning that lets them know the code is working that the site is not available. It ought at the very least report the HTTP error code.